# problemas ao submeter formulario

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

Galera desenvolvi um formulário nesse [site](http://agenciafront.com.br/aldeia/evento) em php e javascript la tem um select multiple onde o usuário vai poder selecionar mais de um valor quando envio meu formulário ele chega com todas as informações porem onde existe select multiple ele não aparece nada essa e a linha aonde vai ter o array

```
 <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple
         name="config[]" id="config" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" 
         title="Configurações do evento"> 



<select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker" multiple
         data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Selecione os equipamentos"
         name="equip[]" id="equip" required>
```

a questão aqui é que não sei como fazer a chamada dessas tags `name="config[]"` ou `name="equip[]"` por exemplo no meu código php ou javascript alguém poderia me ajudar segue os códigos do projeto:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-budget" id="form-elements" onSubmit="return false">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 center">
                                    <div id="result"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="name" id="name" required/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu Email" name="email" id="email" required/>
                                <input type="tel" placeholder="Digite seu Telefone" name="phone" id="phone" class="phone_with_ddd" required/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Data do evento" name="date" id="date" class="date" required/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple
                                        name="config[]" id="config[]"
                                        data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Configurações do evento">
                                    <option value="Mesas-Cadeiras" selected>Mesas e cadeiras</option>
                                    <option value="Auditório" selected>Auditório</option>
                                    <option value="Lounge">Lounge</option>
                                    <option value="Galeria">Galeria</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Quantidade de pessoas" name="quant" id="quant" class="quant" required/>

                                <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker" multiple
                                        data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Selecione os equipamentos"
                                        name="equip[]" id="equip[]" required>
                                    <option value="Projetor">Projetor</option>
                                    <option value="Som">Caixa de som</option>
                                    <option value="Flip-Chart">Flip-Chart</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_btn">Enviar orçamento</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

JS:

```
//Contact Us
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    //get input field values
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var user_date       = $('input[name=date]').val();
    var user_config     = $('select[name=config] option:selected ').val(); 
    //console.log(user_config);
    var user_quant      = $('input[name=quant]').val();
    var user_equip      = $('select[name=equip] option:selected').val();
    //var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //simple validation at client's end
    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if(user_name==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_email==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_phone=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    if(user_quant=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_date=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if(proceed)
    {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userDate':user_date, 'userConfig':user_config, 'userQuant':user_quant, 'userEquip':user_equip};

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response){

            //load json data from server and output message
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#form-elements input').val('');
                $('#form-elements textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)

{
    $to_Email       = "felipe@agenciafront.com.br"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Orçamento do site'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userDate"]) || !isset($_POST["userQuant"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone =                  $_POST["userPhone"];
    $user_Date =                   $_POST["userDate"]; 
    $user_Config       =           $_POST["userConfig"];
    $user_Quant =                  $_POST["userQuant"];
    $user_Equip       =            $_POST["userEquip"];
    //$user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'O campo nome não pode ficar vazio'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ultilize um e-mail válido'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Phone)<5) //check emtpy phone
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira um número de telefone'));
        die($output);
    }


    if(strlen($user_Date)<5) //check emtpy date
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira uma data para o evento'));
        die($output);
    }

     if(strlen($user_Quant)<2) //check emtpy date
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira a quantidade de pessoas para o evento'));
        die($output);
    }


    $message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Data do Evento: </strong>". $user_Date ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Quantidade de pessoas: </strong>". $user_Quant ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Configurações do evento: </strong>". $user_Config ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Equipamentos: </strong>". $user_Equip ."<br>";
    //$message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";



    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8';



    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Olá '. $user_Name .' Obrigado pelo seu contato retornaremos em breve.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas não me parece correto o uso de `[]` nos ids...

Comment: obrigado pelo comentário eu já editei a pergunta estava realizando uns testes no código e esqueci de remover do id mais amigo você conseguiu entender minha dúvida na pergunta ? preciso terminar isso ainda hoje e nao tenho ideia de como fazer a chamada do name="config[]" no meu código js e php

Comment: tente usar o $("#form-elements").serialize(); no lugar do post_data = {'userName... e veja o que chega de resultado no seu php, utilizando o var_dump ou print_r

Comment: é para eu colocar so esse código no lugar desse  post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userDate':user_date, 'userConfig':user_config, 'userQuant':user_quant, 'userEquip':user_equip};

Comment: exatamente. Ficará assim:  var post_data = $("#form-elements").serialize();

Comment: acredito que o seu erro seja na hora de pegar o valor do formulário e passar pra variável post_data e o ajax

Comment: @Kirito se o valor das variáveis config e equip aparecerem no var_dump do PHP, me avise para postar como resposta e explicar para alguém que possa vir a ter a mesma dúvida. abraços

Comment: @DiegoAndrade amigo eu comentei essa linha inteira post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userDate':user_date, 'userConfig':user_config, 'userQuant':user_quant, 'userEquip':user_equip}; e vou adicionar o código que vc mandou acima var post_data = $("#form-elements").serialize(); e vou ver o resultado

Comment: @DiegoAndrade se eu edito o código da forma que você me passou ele cai nesse erro aqui que está no php  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));

Comment: Kirito, edite o php, coloque na primeira linha o seguinte trecho de código: var_dump($_POST); die; abra o seu console do navegador, olhe no console o que o php retornou e cole aqui

Comment: @DiegoAndrade coloca isso antes da abertura da tag do <?php

Comment: apareceu isso XHR finished loading: GET "https://www.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i24269!3i37182!1m4!1m3!1i1…ity_class!2s0!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e3!12m1!5b1&token=59946".
(anonymous) @ VM193:1
eH @ util.js:142
_.fH @ util.js:142
(anonymous) @ onion.js:19
iW.load @ onion.js:65
lW @ onion.js:23
jW.l @ onion.js:65

Comment: após a abertura da tag <?php.

Comment: @Kirito o local que vc irá verificar este retorno do post, é quando vc abre o "inspecionar elemento", na aba network. Lá, irão aparecer as requisições que seu site está fazendo. Clique na página contact.php. que é a que o ajax faz a requisição, e vá em "response". Lá, deverá imprimir o resultado do print_r($_POST);. É disso que preciso

Comment: @DiegoAndrade array(7) { ["userName"]=> string(21) "felipe henrique silva" ["userEmail"]=> string(29) "felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com" ["userPhone"]=> string(14) "(11) 43710-555" ["userDate"]=> string(10) "21/32/1231" ["userConfig"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "Mesas-Cadeiras" [1]=> string(10) "Auditório" } ["userQuant"]=> string(6) "555555" ["userEquip"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Projetor" [1]=> string(10) "Flip-Chart" } }

Comment: no var dump que te mandei acima ele apareceu todas as infos porque no meu html na tag name="config[]" eu retirei esses conchetes e ao refazer o teste com os conchetes olha como ficou

array(5) { ["userName"]=> string(21) "felipe henrique silva" ["userEmail"]=> string(29) "felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com" ["userPhone"]=> string(14) "(11) 43710-555" ["userDate"]=> string(10) "55/55/5555" ["userQuant"]=> string(3) "666" }

Comment: @Kirito caso a minha resposta esteja correta, se puder marcar como resposta correta eu agradeço! abraços e espero ter ajudado

Comment: @DiegoAndrade amigo eu comente em baixo da sua resposta você chegou a dar uma olhadinha ? ta dando um probleminha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está na definição da variável js "post_data" com os dados que vc enviara pelo ajax.

```
//data to be sent to server
post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userDate':user_date, 'userConfig':user_config, 'userQuant':user_quant, 'userEquip':user_equip};
```

após todas as validações que foram feitas acima disso, como você irá utilizar todos os campos do formulário para enviar para o ajax, vc pode utilizar o [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/),

```
var post_data = $("#form-elements").serialize();
```

que pega todos os campos do formulário e transforma em uma string com os nomes dos inputs e os valores em formato de objeto codificado. Assim, vc fará o envio pelo ajax e conseguirá trabalhar com as informações desejadas lá.

**Edit:**
Depois, alterando os nomes das variáveis para os nomes respectivamente enviados, tanto na validação, quanto na atribuição dos valores, deve funcionar.
Para transformar o array em string, faça da seguinte forma?
substitua as 2 linhas onde vc atribui as variáveis user_Config e user_Equip por isso:

```
$user_Config       =           implode(", ",$_POST["config"]);   
$user_Equip       =            implode(", ",$_POST["equip"]);
```

abraços

Comment: amigo ao fazer isso ele cai em um erro no meu php que está nessa linha if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userDate"]) || !isset($_POST["userQuant"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));
        die($output);
    }

se eu editar meu JS assim no php tem alguma mudança?

Comment: acredito que essa seja a resposta mais so preciso saber agora porque so cai nessa condição quando edito meu código para  esse que você mandou ele so cai na condição mencionada acesse o site aonde esta o formulário que você vera o erro

Comment: adicionei um var dump logo abaixo do if(!isset($_POST["userName"] ....))
para ver oque aparece no console

array(7) { ["name"]=> string(21) "felipe henrique silva" ["email"]=> string(29) "felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com" ["phone"]=> string(14) "(11) 43710-555" ["date"]=> string(10) "23/45/4235" ["config"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "Auditório" [1]=> string(6) "Lounge" } ["quant"]=> string(6) "666666" ["equip"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Projetor" [1]=> string(3) "Som" } }

Comment: opa, desculpa @Kirito, não tinha visto. Vc deu var_dump($_POST) e ele retornou estes dados a seguir?? array(7) { ["name"]=> string(21) "felipe henrique silva" ["email"]=> string(29) "felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com" ["phone"]=> string(14) "(11) 43710-555" ["date"]=> string(10) "23/45/4235" ["config"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "Auditório" [1]=> string(6) "Lounge" } ["quant"]=> string(6) "666666" ["equip"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Projetor" [1]=> string(3) "Som" } }

Comment: se foi isso, confira o nome das variáveis que vc está enviando, com os nomes das variáveis que estão na condição. Eles devem ser idênticos: if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userDate"]) || !isset($_POST["userQuant"]))

Comment: amigo no caso as variaveis que estão dentro do meu if tem que ser iguais as que deu no vardump

Comment: ficando assim if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["phone"]) || !isset($_POST["date"]) || !isset($_POST["quant"]))

Comment: exatamente. Deu certo?

Comment: Amigo posso te adicionar no facebook ou skype para você dar uma ultuima olhada? ele paraou de cair naquela condição  e ta enviando normal mais ainda não recebo no email os campos que tem o selectpicker

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59647/discussion-between-kirito-and-diego-andrade).

Comment: skype diegosalamex

Comment: Ja vou adicionar

Comment: já enviei a solicitação

Answer (score 2):

Olha, no PHP não vai fazer a menor diferença como você chama o select, até porque você está fazendo um post com os dados deste formulário.

Se você der uma olhada no fiddle abaixo, basicamente eu repliquei o código de um dos seus selects e coloquei um JS bem simples para printar o que ele produz no final:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($('#select-picker option:selected'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple name="config[]" id="config[]" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Configurações do evento">
                                    <option value="Mesas-Cadeiras" selected>Mesas e cadeiras</option>
                                    <option value="Auditório" selected>Auditório</option>
                                    <option value="Lounge">Lounge</option>
                                    <option value="Galeria">Galeria</option>
                                </select>
<button type="button">
ok</button>
```

Veja que ele printa um array de objetos, cujos dois primeiros elementos são os elementos que você selecionou, então como você já tem um ID no seu elemento, então você pode só iterar pelos valores mais ou menos assim:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  var selected = $('#select-picker option:selected')
  
  for(var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    console.log(selected[i].value)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple name="config[]" id="config[]" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Configurações do evento">
                                        <option value="Mesas-Cadeiras" selected>Mesas e cadeiras</option>
                                        <option value="Auditório" selected>Auditório</option>
                                        <option value="Lounge">Lounge</option>
                                        <option value="Galeria">Galeria</option>
                                    </select>
    <button type="button">
    ok</button>
```

Só que você monta um array com os valores e manda isso pelo post para o PHP, você vai receber um array do outro lado e pode tratar da forma que você quiser.